# creep error in Prolog when I find a route

Tags: recursion, routes, prolog, transitive-closure

I'm learning Prolog, and I'm getting creep error when I try to find a route.
I think what I did is recursion because that's the way to find a route when there's not a straight path.

Here is the code:

```
route(london,paris).
route(paris,rome).
route(rome,spain).
route(london,berlin).
route(berlin,praga).
route(london,dublin).
route(dublin,berlin).

path(X,Y,[X,Y]):- straight(X,Y).
path(X,Z,[X | other]):- straight(X,Y), path(Y,Z,other).
```

when I try to find, let's say the route from London to Rome

```
path(london,rome,Store).
```

I get this error:

```
Exception: (8) straight(london, rome) ? creep

Exception: (7) path(london, rome, _G4705) ? creep
```

What am I doing wrong?
Should I define something else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your predicate is almost correct. You just need to write the tail of the list as a variable `Other` instead of an atom `other` and secondly use your facts route/2 for a straight connection:

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y]) :-
    route(X,Y).
path(X,Z,[X | Other]) :-
    route(X,Y),
    path(Y,Z,Other).
```

Now your query works:

```
   ?- path(london,rome,S).
S = [london,paris,rome] ? ;
no
```